# Sending email from a web api

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-web-api, smtpclient

I want to know how to setup my **info@*****.com** account and send email from this in my c# web API application.

I configured some code like this:

```
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Host = "173.***.**.**";
    client.Port = 25;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;               
    client.EnableSsl = true;
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You have your own smtp relay? Assuming by your usage of `173.***...`.

Comment: The code you have above is incomplete. It'll set up the SMTP client, but you're missing the message to be sent. One of the answers below has that piece

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect a more precise example of what appears to be missing from your configuration. See the history of my answer if you want to see my first example using Google/Gmail SMTP.

Comment: Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

enableSSL might be causing some problems, try switching it off and go from there if working.

Answer (score 0):

Appears you are at a minimum missing the following:

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("info@*****.com");
mailMessage.To.Add("info@*****.com");
mailMessage.Body = "body";
mailMessage.Subject = "subject";
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

the complete code should be

```
 SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
            var mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("yourmail@hotmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("tomail@foo.com.br");
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string htmlBody;
            htmlBody = "Write some HTML code here";
            mail.Body = htmlBody;
            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourmail@hotmail.com", "pwd");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```